# ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.21.2 pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip, easyocr

## **When I want to install the easyocr library, this error occurs.**

`pip install easyocr`

```
C:\Users\Bouregag Youcef>pip install easyocr
Collecting easyocr
  Using cached easyocr-1.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: torch in c:\users\bouregag youcef\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision>=0.5 in c:\users\bouregag youcef\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (0.15.1)
Collecting opencv-python-headless<=4.5.4.60
  Using cached opencv-python-headless-4.5.4.60.tar.gz (89.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-67.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
      Collecting scikit-build
        Downloading scikit_build-0.17.1-py3-none-any.whl (81 kB)
           ---------------------------------------- 82.0/82.0 kB 1.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting cmake
        Using cached cmake-3.26.3-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (33.0 MB)
      Collecting pip
        Downloading pip-23.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
           ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 4.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.21.2 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.22.2, 1.22.3, 1.22.4, 1.23.0rc1, 1.23.0rc2, 1.23.0rc3, 1.23.0, 1.23.1, 1.23.2, 1.23.3, 1.23.4, 1.23.5, 1.24.0rc1, 1.24.0rc2, 1.24.0, 1.24.1, 1.24.2)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.21.2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

## **Although I already installed numpy 1.24.2, this error occurs and I do not know its cause.**

`pip show  numpy`

```
C:\Users\Bouregag Youcef>pip show  numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.24.2
Summary: Fundamental package for array computing in Python
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email:
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: C:\Users\Bouregag Youcef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: camelot-py, contourpy, img2table, matplotlib, opencv-python, opencv-python-headless, pandas, pyarrow, scikit-learn, scipy, tab
```

I've tried updating the numpy library and still the same issue

Python 3.11.0
numpy  1.24.2
windows 10